# Unable to install Opera in Fedora 28 using rpm

Tags: fedora, rpm

1. I can't install the program by double-click because it conflicts with previously installed opera.
2. I can't install opera via the following command:

   rpm -ivh opera-stable_56.0.3051.52_amd64.rpm

because

```
libXss.so.1()(64bit) is needed by opera-stable-56.0.3051.52-0.x86_64
```

ButtI don't Know how to get this object file (?) on my Fedora. `dnf` don't know about this package. Neither does `apt-get` nor `yum`.

OS: Fedora 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A search on rpmfind](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXss.so.1()(64bit)) reveals that the package you need on Fedora 28 is `libXScrnSaver`. Do `yum install libXScrnSaver` and then you should be able to install Opera.

You can also use yum to install one-off RPMs, so that it can try to automatically install dependencies, like this: `yum install ./opera-stable_56.0.3051.52_amd64.rpm`

Comment: @imidazole If your problem is solved, please click the check mark by my answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the missing package is `at` instead of `libXss.so.1`.  Looks like it's not available on Fedora 28???

Comment: @Alex Fedora 28 is EOL, so it has security vulnerabilities that will never be fixed, and as such should no longer be used. For this reason, rpmfind no longer indexes Fedora 28's packages. It does exist, though.

Comment: One thing you might want to edit into your answer, which has resolved this issue for me.  Using `rpm` to install a package requires all dependencies to be installed already.  On the other hand, using `yum` would allow the system to resolve these dependencies for you.  Furthermore, http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/limit/7/srodzaj/1/dl/40/search/libXss.so.1%28%29%2864bit%29/field[]/1/field[]/2 allows one to search packages for older versions also.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Alex My answer already says to use yum, and I don't want to make it easier for people to do unsafe things like continuing to use an EOL OS.

Comment: What I meant was not that my solution is better (otherwise, I would post my own answer to this question), but that I give an explanation regarding why `rpm` gives this particular error.  If you don't wish to edit your answer, then please let me know, and I can post this as an answer anyways.

Comment: @Alex Answer updated to include using yum to install the RPM.